# How to call a function out of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in html, I write follow:

```
<div ng-controller="cxController">
   <my-dir test-data="testdata"></my-dir>
 </div>
```

in the cxController, I write follow:

```
$scope.testdata={
  spanInfo:{},
  buttonInfo:{}
};
$scope.click1=function(){};
$scope.click2=function(){};
$scope.click3=function(){};
```

in directive, there are some spans and buttons. and the button number is not set,  I need to use ng-repeat to write it. But the button has click function: click1,click2,click3 and so on. How can I call the function click1,click2... in the directive?

To tell the directive there are some functions in buttonInfo like this?

```
$scope.testdata={
  spanInfo:{},
  buttonInfo:{
    {click:$scope.click1}
    {click:$scope.click2}
  }
};
```

Comment: What `scope` property does the directive have? Also, why just just use one method that accepts an *"index"* argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way , that I am used to call a controller function from a directive.
Can you make use of this?

your directive

```
(function() {
    'use strict'; 
    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('myDir', myDir);

    myDir.$inject = [];

    function myDir() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: { 
                onClick : '&' ,
            },
            template: '<div>'+
                        '<button ng-click="onClick()"></button'+
                     '</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        }
    }
})();
```

controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = [];

    function myController() {

        var vm = this;

        vm.callControllerFn = function(){
            alert("called")
        }

    }
})();
```

View

```
<my-dir on-click="vmA.callControllerFn();"></my-dir>
```